# Apply a single trigger procedure to many different tables

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.1

In my PostgreSQL 9.1 database I have multiple tables and one trigger function.

Right now I am creating the trigger for each table by using that trigger function.

This methodology working fine. My boss has asked me to create the trigger commonly (only one time) by re-using that trigger function. That one trigger function should get used by all the tables in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example of creating a trigger with dynamic SQL using PL/PgSQL in the [Audit Trigger](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) sample for PostgreSQL. The same approach will work with any other DDL.

See the function `audit.audit_table` and use of `format` and `EXECUTE` there.

That said, needing to create tables procedurally can be (but isn't always) a sign of questionable schema design.

Simple example of dynamic SQL creating a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo_dynamic_table(tablename text) RETURNS void AS $$                                                                                      
BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                          
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I (id serial primary key);', tablename);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The same approach works for trigger creation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time spending on this,  `SELECT audit.audit_table('target_table_name', 'true', 'false', '{version_col, changed_by, changed_timestamp}'::text[]);` In this procudure they are passing singe table name as the first parameter, can i pass all of my table in that parameter?

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. "All of your table"? Do you mean *all your tables* ie a list of table names?

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. If you want to pass in a list of all your tables, you could pass an array or use a `VARIADIC` function, but it's better to just call the function on a set, eg `SELECT create_my_trigger(tablename) FROM (VALUES('table1'),('table2'),('table3')) tablenames(tablename);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create PL/pgSQL procedure for table creation and move your trigger creation code inside it

Comment: Obviously your suggestion will create triggers for each tables in my database, what my boss looking for is to create 1 trigger for all of the 20 tables. in other words, it may be a shared trigger. is there any possibilities to do so.?